# How to center content on screen and scroll if it overflows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have as screen that is centered using:

```
SafeArea(
   child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Center(
                  child: ...,
              ),
          ),
      ],
   ),
)
```

But if the content is larger than the screen size, it will overflow. How can I keep the content centered, but at the same time start scrolling if it overflows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ListView` widget and then put your content into it's `children`

Like so:

```
SafeArea(
   child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                      child: ...,
                  ),
              ]
          ),
      ],
   ),
)
```

Replace your column with a `ListView`.

Comment: I followed your logic, but needed to add a Center before the ListView, shrinkWrap it, and remove the Expanded. Then it worked flawlessly, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following @Tembero's logic, I added a `shrinkWrap`ed `ListView`, removed the `Expanded`, and wrapped the ListView in a `Center` widget, so now it behaves exactly as expected:

```
SafeArea(
    child: Center(
        child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
            Center(
                child: ...
            ),
        ],
        ),
    ),
)
```